# Why the "T" prefix in TObject?

Tags: delphi, tobject

When declaring classes and so on, what does the "T" in `TObject` stand for? Template?

Example:

```
procedure TfrmMain.CaptureInfo1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmCapture.Show;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for "Type", as far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

Delphi has a number of officially sanctioned prefixes.
These are all by Borland convention and are not enforced by the compiler.

```
Prefix | Used for | Notes
-------+----------+---------------------------------------------
   T   | types    | Denotes a structured type, class or record
   I   |interfaces| For interfaces, e.g. IInterface
   F   | Field    | Private Field in a class or record
  xx   | enum     | Enumeration members have a 2 char prefix
       |          | e.g.  fsBold, fsItalic for the TFontStyle enum  
   A   | params   | deprecated ! All method params at one point started with an `A`.
                    this convention is no longer encouraged. 

Note that the capitalization is as shown.
```

The reason Delphi uses prefixes is that the language is not case sensitive, so the C/Java trick of using ALLCAPS for constants and Leading caps for types does not work.

All this and more is outlined in the [Object Pascal Style Guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280), more specifically the section [Naming Convention](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280#3.0).
<sub>It's the style that all source code written by Borland et al follow</sub>

Comment: I kind of like the `A` prefix, though, since it reduces the risk of conflicts or confusion. It does happen that I write `FLimit := ALimit`, for instance.

Comment: sometimes I put a small [e] in front of enumerations, where a user-defined TFontStyle enumeration would be eFontStyle.

Comment: But I recently switched to et for Enumeration Type, to make the code completion lists smaller.